# Laravel Routing in package

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a laravel package but my routes.php can't find my controller...
My package is called Blackbird\Bluebird and in my app.php settings file dashboard_uri is equal to 'admin'.

If I replace the Route::controller to Route::resource it al works find in my public directory, if I then switch to public/admin I get this error: Class Blackbird\Bluebird\Controllers\DashboardController does not exist. Note that it if I use Route::controller I get the error on the public directory aswell.

I already run composer dump-autoload...

What are my options?

routes.php:

```
$dashboardUrl = Config::get('bluebird::app.dashboard_url');

Route::controller($dashboardUrl, 'Blackbird\Bluebird\Controllers\DashboardController');
```

DashboardController.php:

```
<?php namespace Blackbird\Bluebird\Controllers;

class DashboardController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex()
{
        return View::make('bluebird::dashboard'); // Opens View/Dashboard.blade.php
    }

    // Some more code...

}
```

Comment: Is your package currently sitting in your workbench or in your vendor folder? For packages which are still in workbench, you'll need to run `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: Yea it is still in my workbench and I did run the `php artisan` command!